# Why is the frame title height reduced, when using shadow outer theme?

Tags: beamer, shading, shadows, frame-title

I want to have a horizontal shading in my frame title, so I can put a logo on the right side of the title. To have this in my frames, It seems that I have to use shadow outer theme. the problem is that by using this theme the frame title height decreases and when trying to define frame title height by \setbeamertemplate{frametitle} ... the frame title disappears.

The code is as below (The output is as the first image) and if I remove shadow outer theme and shading description, the frame title height goes back to its normal value (as in the second image).

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shading}
\useoutertheme{shadow}

\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Madrid}
}

\colorlet{titleleft}{blue!50!black}
\colorlet{titlethreequarter}{blue!50!black}
\colorlet{titleright}{white}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titlethreequarter,titleright]
{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{
color(0pt)=(titleleft);
color(0.75\paperwidth)=(titlethreequarter)
color(0.9\paperwidth)=(titleright)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
\end{frame}

\end{document
```

[image: Image No. 1]

[image: Image No. 2]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide minimal working example,  a complete small document,which show your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not like how the frametitle is defined in the `shadow` outer theme, you can tweak it according to your needs. See the example below, there are two places where you can increase the spacing above and below the font. I marked my additions by `%%%%%%%%%%%`.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\useoutertheme{shadow}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Madrid}
}

\colorlet{titleleft}{blue!50!black}
\colorlet{titlethreequarter}{blue!50!black}
\colorlet{titleright}{white}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titlethreequarter,titleright]{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{
    color(0pt)=(titleleft);
    color(0.75\paperwidth)=(titlethreequarter);
    color(0.9\paperwidth)=(titleright)
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \vskip-2pt%
    \hbox{\leavevmode
        \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
        \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
        \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
        \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
            \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
                    \vbox{}\vskip.5ex%%%%%%%%%%% above the font
                    \leftskip0.3cm%
                    \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
                    \insertframetitle%
                    \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
                    \strut\par%
                    \else
                    \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
                    \fi%
                    \nointerlineskip
                    \vskip.65ex%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% below the font
                    \vbox{}%
                \end{minipage}}%
                \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
                \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
                \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
                    \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
                    \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
                    \pgfusepath{clip}
                    \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
                \end{pgfpicture}
                \hskip-\paperwidth%
                \box\beamer@tempbox%
            }%
            \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
        }%
        \nointerlineskip
        \vskip-0.2pt
        \hbox to\textwidth{\hskip-\Gm@lmargin\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin}
        \vskip-2pt
    }




\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Frame Title}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Frame Title}
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sam. It solved my problem. I really appreciate your help.